# Xamarin:Get the absolute path of files in Assets Folder

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I just want get the absolute path of my "test.pdf" in Assets folder in **Visual studio Xamarin(2015)**. How should i do that?

```
            using System;
            using System.IO;
            using Android.App;
            using Android.Content;
            using Android.Widget;
            using Android.OS;
            using Com.Artifex.Mupdfdemo;
            using Java.IO;
            using File = Java.IO.File;

            var file = (File)fileFromAsset(this, "test.pdf");
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.AbsolutePath);
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MuPDFActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
            intent.SetData(uri);
            this.StartActivity(intent);
```

But in second line i face with error with **(file.AbsolutePath)** :

*'object' does not contain a definition for 'AbsolutePath' and no extension method 'AbsolutePath' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  PdfTest2    F:\Projects\PdfTest2\PdfTest2\PdfTest2\MainActivity.cs*

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I should use **AbsolutePath()** in **Java.IO.File** to get the absolute path of files.

Then I put my file from Assets folder with cast conversion in a Java.IO.File object (file).

```
            File file = (File)fileFromAsset(this, "test.pdf");
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.AbsolutePath);
```

Comment: What is fileFromAsset?

Comment: fileFromAsset get file from a folder called "Asset", in xamarin.android projects